# How to use a script to open a website and click a button or do something else?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I am trying to write a script to use a script to open a website and click a button.

I can actually use `window.location.href = '...';` or `$("#id").click()` to do that separately. But if I run the first one, the second one wouldn't run because we would lose it.

I just want to know is there any way to run the code one by one?

update:
No I can't control it. It is a public website.

Comment: Just put the second part in the page your navigating to and it will run when it loads?

Comment: Do you control the second page?

Comment: Javascript lives on *one* page, on every redirect it will stop running. You have to use some kind of browser addon or whatever to run js cross page.

Comment: @bambam lol I guess that would matter huh? Figured he did if not i don't know how you would do this either.

Comment: I can't control it ...

Comment: If it is a public website, then you have to use the Userscripts

Comment: Make use of Greasemonkey for FF or TamperMonkey for Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, but you can only use it in your own browser (or in anyones browser who has this userscript installed). For example, for tampermonkey in chrome you could use

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Button clicker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Click a button
// @author       You
// @match        <replace with website you want the button to be clicked>
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.getElementById('id').click();
})();
```

Comment: It is a good idea. But actually it doesn't work in my website i don't know why. This website  
 https://secure.timesheets.com/?CFID=239387727&CFTOKEN=a1d7cde00b4d84f8-554A5D51-5056-850F-66D6C0144776E3ED It works if I just put the click js code in console, it can click the button but doesn't if I put it in the script. It would just looks like refresh the page and the following CFID code in the url change to another one.

Comment: Which button do you want to click there @WeihengLi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971986/tampermonkey-cant-click-button You can find more info here.